# Cant get data from table with foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Im working on a webapi project with EF and and sqlserver.
Now when I trying to get for ex IEnumerable its works and show me all employees on xml file .(Employee dont have foreign key only primary).
when I ask other controller for ex IEnumerable its give me the

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

Error.
any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ok thank for help actually already saw those topics but missed a part there,any way i just added those lines:

this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

in the dbContext ctor and it worked.
now try to understand what those line are